# Calculate COGS with average method in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an inventory transaction table. I want to calculate COGS with average method for each row

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleData]
    (
        [date]       [datetime] NULL,
        [product_id] [varchar](15) NULL,
        [Qty]        [decimal](18,2) NULL,
        [price]      [money] NULL,
        [progress]   [varchar](10) NULL,
    )
        
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20170228', 'SLG00034', 86.5, 3300, 'IN') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20170307', 'SLG00034', -5, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20170312', 'SLG00034', -1, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20170318', 'SLG00034', -1, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20170511', 'SLG00034', 100, 3380, 'IN') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20170518', 'SLG00034', -0.5, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20170522', 'SLG00034', -2, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20170604', 'SLG00034', -2, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20180606', 'SLG00034', 20, 6000, 'IN') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20180720', 'SLG00034', -0.5, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20180728', 'SLG00034', -4, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20180827', 'SLG00034', -4, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20180907', 'SLG00034', -1, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20191213', 'SLG00034', 10, 7000, 'IN') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20200710', 'SLG00034', 20, 4500, 'IN') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20200926', 'SLG00034', -0.5, 0, 'OUT') 
    INSERT INTO sampledata VALUES ('20201004', 'SLG00034', -215, 0, 'OUT')
```

Desired output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4QNH.png

anybody pls help, i cant figure out avgcost as image above

**Edit**

I need to calculate closing avgcost for each row with rules :

- (Open amount + In amount)÷(Open unit + In unit) = Avg cost per unit
- Average cost per unit * Units sold = Cost of Goods Sold
- Average cost per unit * closing unit = closing inventory amount

closing inventory amount we will use as an opening amount in next row

closing unit we will use as an opening unit in next row

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You've provided a desired output but didn't describe the rules. Should we develop *some* algorithm that will show this data for this source data? It is quite simple: just select constants from nothing, but I presume it is not what you want. Please, update your question and describe how to calculate what you want and what is wrong with your current attempt

Answer (score 1):

I came across this FIFO solution a long time ago.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18711.t-sql-fifo-inventory-problem-cost-of-goods-sold.aspx

This may help too.

http://westclintech.com/Blog/EntryId/136/Inventory-Calculations-in-SQL-Server